# How to Work with PopAsync page navigation animation from right to left?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Please tell me how to apply an animation page effect coming from right to left when I call PopAsync().

My Code:

```
    async void LogOut_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`PopAsync` has an [override](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.PopAsync/p/System.Boolean/) that accepts a boolean to indicate if it should animate. If you call it using `Navigation.PopAsync(true)` it will perform the animation when popping the page.

Comment: i want the right to left animation when page pop up . and i have make renderer of navigation page in ios in which i have override the PopViewController method of UIViewController. not call PopViewController

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/AlexandrNikulin/AnimationNavigationPage amazing library. The following code blocks come from the project README (possibly slightly adapted, credits to [Alexandr Nikulin](https://github.com/AlexandrNikulin)):

**Usage**

```
public class App : Application
{
        public App()
        {
            MainPage = new AnimationNavigationPage(new YourHomePage());
        }
}
```

Create AnimationPage instead ContentPage and create instance of FadePageAnimation or PushPageAnimation or FlipPageAnimation etc in xaml or bind from ViewModel.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<controls:AnimationPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:FormsControls.Base;assembly=FormsControls.Base"
        x:Class="Sample.FadeAnimationPage"
        Title="Fade Animation">
        <controls:AnimationPage.PageAnimation>
            <controls:FadePageAnimation />
        </controls:AnimationPage.PageAnimation>
</controls:AnimationPage>
```

Or implement interface IAnimationPage for ContentPage. Create instance of EmptyPageAnimation or DefaultPageAnimation or FlipPageAnimation etc...

```
public partial class FirstPage : ContentPage, IAnimationPage
{
        public FirstPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        public IPageAnimation PageAnimation { get; } = new FlipPageAnimation { Duration = 650, Subtype = AnimationSubtype.FromLeft }; 
}
```

Comment: [AnimationNavigationPage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XForms.Plugin.AnimationNavigationPage) was last updated on `27/11/2019` and could potentially contain new bugs and it doesn't seem to have a big support.